# VLOOKUP alternative with less than or equal to operator and with the ability to use in an ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets

The range `Current!E5:E` contains values which can be any random value. In range `Configuration!D5:E` I have a key and value list which I would like to get a result from.

I'd like for the range `Current!G5:G` to show the results. The key should be chosen if it is less than or equal to the user's credits.

I have included a `Desired outcome` worksheet to visualize my desired outcome.

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1icDp-hWkxzRcNszmkZIr8KIQ6KAv1h6Jld7nkfeT-iU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete everything from G4:G (including the header) and place the following formula in G4:

`=ArrayFormula({"Credit earned points:";IF(E5:E="",,VLOOKUP(E5:E,SORT(FILTER(Configuration!D5:E,Configuration!D5:D<>""),1,1),2,TRUE))})`

This will create the header (which can change within the formula if you like).

`VLOOKUP` looks up the credits within a flipped version of the 'Configuration' data and using `TRUE` as the final parameter, which will bump backward to the last value if an exact value cannot be found.

Comment: You're a pro-gamer my dude! Thanks for the help and the explanation, you're awesome!

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for marking the post "Best Answer," which will alert other contributors that this issue has been fully resolved.